# Semi-transparent division with graduated transparency of borderr

Tags: html, css

I've got a box with a rounded border that needs to start off at 80% opaque and fade gradually until at the bottom it is 20% opaque. Meanwhile, the border needs to start off at 80% opaque and finish off transparent.

I found some CSS3 information on graduated fill on borders and tried it using rgba but it didn't work on Firefox which is the browsers most of my target audience use.
I found two ways of doing it using pseudo-classes but neither are perfect. I was hoping, if post these methods and say what the problems were, someone could suggest how to improve them.

I need to do it by CSS without adding extra divisions or anything like that to the HTML if possible.

HTML

```
 <div class="box">
  <div>
    <h3>Box 1</h3>        
    <div>
      <p>Content.</p>
      <p>More content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Method 1

```
.box, .box:before, .box:after{
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    behavior: url(htc/border-radius.htc);
}
.box:before{
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(69,174,189,0.8),rgba(69,174,189,0));
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(69,174,189,0.8)),to(rgba(69,174,189,0)));
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=rgba(69,174,189,0.8),endColorStr=rgba(69,174,189,0));
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px; left: -4px; bottom: -4px; right: -4px;
    z-index: -2;
}
.box:after{
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(76,91,198,0.8),rgba(76,91,198,0.2));
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(76,91,198,0.8)),to(rgba(76,91,198,0.2)));
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=rgba(76,91,198,0.8),endColorStr=rgba(76,91,198,0.2));
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.box{
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
}
.box div{
    background-color:transparent;
}
.box div div{
    padding: 0 7px;
}

.box h3 {
    border: 0;
    background:transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

This code does what I want but the transparency of the box it not brilliant since the other box is behind it. It's not too bad on smaller boxes but with boxes that have a lot of content it doesn't look very good.

CSS Method 2

```
.box, .box:before, .box:after{
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
    behavior: url(htc/border-radius.htc);
}
.box{
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(76,91,198,0.8),rgba(76,91,198,0.2));
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(76,91,198,0.8)),to(rgba(76,91,198,0.2)));
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=rgba(76,91,198,0.8),endColorStr=rgba(76,91,198,0.2));
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: rgba(69,174,189,0.8);
}
.box:before, .box:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    width: 4px;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(69,174,189,0.8),rgba(69,174,189,0));
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(rgba(69,174,189,0.8)),to(rgba(69,174,189,0)));
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr=rgba(69,174,189,0.8),endColorStr=rgba(69,174,189,0));
}
.box:after{
    left: auto;
    right: -5px;
}

.box div{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.box div div{
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.box h3{
    border: 0;
    background:transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

This one has the transparency fine on the box although the borders aren’t as good. The main problem is there is a small gap at the bottom which I can't figure out and the 'borders' on the left and right overlap the top border and moving them down means they still don't join onto the top border.

The first option works best but as I've mentioned above it not perfect. Is there any way I can't get either of these to work better or am I taking the completely wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to go without applying the gradient to the top and bottom border you could do something like this. It just means your gradient starts and stops before the in between the border raduses.

Looks good to me, but I don't know your specific use case.
Also, obviously IE9 and earlier don't support gradients.

http://jsfiddle.net/vXzRz/2/

```
.box {
    position: relative;    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.8)), to(rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.2)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.8), rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.2));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.8), rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.2));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.8), rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.2));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.8), rgba(159, 195, 192, 0.2));
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.box > div {
    border-radius: 12px;
}


.box:before,
.box:after {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    width: 4px;
    top: 13px;
    bottom: 9px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(14, 131, 123, .8)), to(rgba(14, 131, 123, 0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(14, 131, 123, .8), rgba(14, 131, 123, 0));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(14, 131, 123, .8), rgba(14, 131, 123, 0));
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(14, 131, 123, .8), rgba(14, 131, 123, 0));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(14, 131, 123, .8), rgba(14, 131, 123, 0));
}
.box:before {
    left: -4px;
}
.box:after {
    right: -4px;
}
.box > div:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    left: -4px;
    height: 13px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 17px;
    border-top-right-radius: 17px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(14, 131, 123, .8);
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Tested in current versions of Chrome, FF, IE10, Safari, Opera

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle and it looks okay. I'll give it a try and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution. You will have to play with the dimensions, position, and border radius to get kt looking right if you want to change the border width. But it certainly looks better than either of the options you had listed. And if you used sass you could probably write some code to take care of the alterations for you based on border width.

Comment: That is a MASSIVE improvement. Thank you so much. By the way, what is "sass"?

Comment: Sass is a css extension and pre-processor. It is very helpful if you do a lot of work with css. http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Thanks. I'll investigate that.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the inner div? I tried using .box p:first-chld:before which works, however it look like it could be 100% opaque. 
I'd like to be able to remove some of the divs. Can this been done?

Comment: Yes, as long as the child you are adding the pseudo element to is static. http://jsfiddle.net/vXzRz/4/ I'm not sure what you mean by "it looks like it could be 100% opaque"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vXzRz/5/ I added a background pattern so you can see the opacity better.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem I had was using something that had more than one child and I did it incorrectly.

Comment: I tried using: .box > *:first-child and that worked however if I have a floated div inside it will stop where that div starts. Do you have any idea why. If I take out the float it works - but then of course, messed up my layout.

Comment: I am unable replciate your issue. Could you edit the last jsfiddle I posted to replicate the issue you are having then post the updated link?

Comment: Okay. I'll have to that tomorrow since I've come up across another unrealted problem that I need to look into first. Although this problem is unrealted, it does involve floating element so it might lead to a solution. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Don't worry about my last problem. I was just being stupid. If they float and object you take it out of the normal flow and so the browser doesn't know how high it is.